# Does the github web platform use a reverse proxy for caching?

Tags: caching, nginx, reverse-proxy, varnish

The github web site is awfully fast and considering it's serving a ton of requests I've been wondering if github uses a reverse proxy something along the line of varnish or nginx?

I have a website that's serving highly dynamic content just like the github web service and I've been wondering if it's possible to front it with a reverse proxy for better performance.

Comment: please take a look what [Github partners described](http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2009/10/load-balancing-at-github-why-ldirectord/) back in 2009: *The return traffic doesn’t even go back through the load balancer at Github, since we’re using a really neat mode of IPVS that allows the traffic to return to the client directly*. From the other side Github Pages architecture [is different](http://githubengineering.com/rearchitecting-github-pages/) through the standard haproxy.